# Concatenate criteria in inner case within Order by clause in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query in SQL Server 2008 and I am trying to order it in the following way:

```
        SELECT  d.DeptId, Description
        FROM    Dept d LEFT JOIN DeptOrder o on p.DeptId = o.DeptId
        WHERE   d.DeptId IN (3, 7, 9, 10, 17, 20)
        ORDER BY
           CASE WHEN @OrderByDescription = 1 THEN Description
                                             ELSE CASE WHEN o.Order IS NULL THEN 1                                                     ELSE 0 
                                                  END, o.Order
           END
```

**Tables**:

Department: Contains a list of departments which has following columns:

- DeptId int
- Description varchar(50)

DeptOrder: Lists the order for departments in company and has the following columns:

- DeptId int
- Order  int (it is a correlative number)

What I am trying to do:
I want to obtain a list of departments with its description order by description if @OrderByDescription = 1. Otherwise, if @OrderByDescription = 0, I want to obtain the list ordered by order field (nulls will be put at the end).

So suppose below examples.

**CASE 1: Some departments in Department table are not in DeptOrder table and @OrderByDescription = 0**

```
Department
DeptId     Description
  1        Financial
  2        Marketing
  3        Communications
  4        I+D
 ... 
  7        Accounting
```

and so on

Suppose DeptOrder table only contains the following departments (This table may not contains some departments. Department not listed here will be put at the end of the list):

```
DeptOrder 
DeptId     Order
  7        1
  3        2
```

The list obtained would be:

DeptId     Description
   7       Accounting
   3       Communications
and then the rest order by o.Order.

**CASE 2**:
Departments in Deptartment table are not in DeptOrder table and @OrderByDescription = 1

```
Department
DeptId     Description
  1        Financial
  2        Marketing
  4        Communications
  5        I+D
  8        Accounting
```

The result would be (ordered by description):

```
Department
DeptId     Description
  8        Accounting
  4        Communications
  1        Financial
  5        I+D
  2        Marketing
```

But I get an sql error when I concatenate ", o.Order" at the end of the second case.

Answer (score 0):

You've got o.Order slightly out of place - it needs to be after the close of the initial case statement:

```
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN OrderByDescription = 1 
        THEN [Description]
        ELSE CASE WHEN o.[Order] IS NULL 
                  THEN '1'
                  ELSE '0'
              END
    END
    ,o.[Order]
```

Comment: When OrderByDescription = 1 I only want to order by Description and not by o.Order. I only want to concatenate o.Order when OrderByDescription = 0

Comment: In that case, if I'm understanding correctly, all you need is one case statement - CASE WHEN OrderByDescription = 1 THEN Description ELSE COALESCE(o.Order,1) END

Comment: not exactly. Take into account taht o.Order may be null so in case when OrderByDescription = 0, I want nulls to be put at the end (for these reason I return 0 or 1) and then I want to order by o.Order, so there are 3 order possibilities: Order by Description, Order by 0,o.Order and Order by 1, o.Order.

Comment: Basically I want to concatenate o.Order to the second case result

Comment: Right, right. So the original answer should work as o.Order only applies after the case statement. You would need to make sure the 1 and 0 are strings rather than int though. When I try it with the data you supplied above it works.